azure smtp server is not recognising my cloudflare mx record
I have an smtp server setup on azure.  I'm using azure function to perform an email verification.  It works locally when I use these settings:
_emailValidation.FromMailServer = "smtp.socialhootz-admin.com";
_emailValidation.FromEmail = "DoNotReply@socialhootz-admin.com";
But when I run if from azure I receive this error:
'DurableTriggerEmailVerifier (Orchestrator)' failed with an error. Reason: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.FunctionFailedException: The activity function 'GetEmailVerification' failed: "Failed MxRecord Check for donotreply@socialhootz-admin.com: No Mx Records Found". See the function execution logs for additional details
I've checked that I have mx records on cloudflare account and I can see them clearly.
Cloudflare
I've also, use several online mx checking tools and sure enough it's seeing them.  But for some reason Azure keeps complaining even though it's working fine on my local azure function instance.
I tried searching for mx setting on azure and thinking it might be trying to find mx records of it's own.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
